# Formvalidation.io - Validate fields based on value of other fields

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, formvalidation.io

I have been trying to find the solution to this for some time now but I am not having much luck.  I'm sure the solution is simple so thanks in advance for the help!

I am using the formvalidation io plugin and have it working perfectly on multiple forms.  I have another large form that I want to validate a customer's name.  I have 3 fields (CompanyName, FirstName, & LastName) in the form and I want to validate based on the following rules:

- CompanyName or FirstName & LastName Required
- If no Company Name is entered the both FirstName & LastName are required
- If CompanyName is entered then FirstName & LastName are not required but either can have a value

Hopefully that all makes sense.  I have figured out how to use a hidden field to require both FirstName and LastName to be entered ([Valdiating multiple inputs as one](http://formvalidation.io/examples/validating-multiple-inputs-one/)).  I'm sure this will require some sort of conditional validation ([Conditional Validation](http://formvalidation.io/examples/conditional-validation/)) to accomplish this but I'm not sure how to implement.

Does anyone have any experience accomplishing something like this?  As I said, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that using callback validator.
Example for company name:

```
companyname: {
                validators : {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'companyname is required',
                        callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                            if(document.getElementById('firstname').value && document.getElementById('lastname').value){
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your js code you can set "data-fv-excluded" attribute true or false depending on the fields you want to validade for example:

```
if(document.getElementById('firstname').value && document.getElementById('lastname').value){
    document.getElementById('companyname').setAttribute("data-fv-excluded", "true");
}
```

The validator will ignore your fields with data-fv-excluded="true"

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this. It work fine for me:

```
companyname: {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'Please Enter first name and last name when company name is empty',
                        callback: function(input) {
                            var companyName = input.value;
                            if (companyName === '') {

                        var firstName = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
                        var latsName = document.getElementById('last_name').value;

                        return (firstName !== '')&&(latsName !== '');
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```